# open a socket on a shared host

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to open a socket on a host using the following code:

```
$timeout = 10;
$s = stream_socket_client('mywebsite.com:80', $errcode, $errstring, $timeout);
$message = "GET /index.php HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($s, $message);
while(!feof($s)){
    echo fread($s, 1024);
}
```

Nothing fancy, just an example I found. The problem is that every time I run the code I get different files. I think this is because the host is a shared one.

Is there a way to overcome this problem, that is, pull reliably the proper file I'm trying to get?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the HTTP request you have to specify which host you're accessing. as you noted correctly multiple DNS entries can point to the same IP address.

```
$message = "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: hostname.com\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: and it has to be HTTP/1.1 request

Comment: correct, upvoted it. just plain curiosity: are there nowadays any web server out there which would ignore that request header when the request is 1.0?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know. But when you sending the correct http version, you give the web server a chance to respond with 505 - not supported response. Otherwise if you hit http 1.0 server, you may receive 500 or 501 response, and not know what to do...

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the `Host` header to specify the domain name - it is very common for one server to host multiple websites:

```
$message = "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\n\r\n";
```

Note (as @[Darhazer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797303/darhazer) points out) that `Host` request header is only defined since HTTP/1.1, so you can't use it wtih HTTP/1.0. There is a possibility to use the absolute URL, as in

```
$message = "GET http://www.example.com/index.php HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
```

but this is a violation of [HTTP/1.0](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#Request-URI):

> The absoluteURI form is only allowed when the request is being made to a proxy.

and the target server apparently isn't a proxy, so the resulting behavior is unreliable.

Comment: and it has to be HTTP/1.1 request

Comment: @Piskvor, thanks for telling me. There is something I learned today